# How to tell Rails assets that new public asset file was generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I have a Rails application that is dynamically creating and compiling assets depending from what domain you are accessing the website (let say different colors, where values of colors are stored in database )

let say for `www.hello.example` it will generate `public/assets/hello-application-52777d36dec6f6e311560156da9da1c2.css` so browser source file  will point to

```
layout:
= stylesheet_link_tag 'hello-application'

generated html:
<link href="/assets/hello-application-52777d36dec6f6e311560156da9da1c2.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If you add `www.goodbye.example` it will compile `public/assets/goodbye-application-52777d36dec6f6e311560156da9da1c2.css` so browser source file will point to

```
layout:
= stylesheet_link_tag 'goodbye-application'

generated html:
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/goodbye-application-52777d36dec6f6e311560156da9da1c2.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Assets are compiled correctly on the fly without need to restart the server.

Examples above work fine if I restart the server

The thing I cannot figure out is **how to tell Rails that new public asset file was generated**  so that `= stylesheet_link_tag 'goodbye-application'` will pick it up **without the need to restart the production server**.

My guess is that it has something to do to tell Rails to reload the `public/manifest.json` I just cannot figure it out

- Rails 4.0.2
- Ruby  2.1
- Unicorn production server

My functionality is kinda similar to [krautcomputing article](http://www.krautcomputing.com/blog/2012/03/27/how-to-compile-custom-sass-stylesheets-dynamically-during-runtime/) however he is solwing this problem with "Digested" which is not  working for rails 4 (+ it will be deprecated soon)

---

**Update**

One dude provided an answer (which he had remove) suggesting I don't need to do this because Unicorn have zero time restart, so I can just restart the unicorn and it will load the new public assets... That's true, I'm doing this this way before I've asked this question. However I'm looking for solution that avoid this. (let say users generate 1000 styles per day)

He also suggested to use Grunt... Well, that's plan B, I'm really wondering if there is a way to do this in Rails-sprockets :)

Comment: how does rails do that right now? what configuration do you use to accomplish the on-the-fly generation right now?

Comment: Aside: You should upgrade from rails v4.0.2 to the latest v4.0 release soon. [v4.0.3](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/2/18/Rails_3_2_17_4_0_3_and_4_1_0_beta2_have_been_released/) introduced several security patches.

Comment: How about making `= stylesheet_link_tag 'Variable' ` depending on what the name of the CSS is going to be generated.
For example the goodbye one will have goodbye.css and the other will have the name you pick ?

Comment: Maybe a bit naive, but you know the exact moment a new asset is added, dish out to the shell (or background task) and run `rake assets:precompile` ? This will generate the `manifest` file. Although not entirely sure if a running rails process will pick it up. It is not as clean as automatically re-compiling, but better then restarting the unicorn process :)

Comment: Rails does not pick up the manifest changes or even a new manifest. I'm looking for a solution for this as well to better simulate my production environment while developing. I've completed an entire gulp drop-in replacement for sprockets, and yet rails does not want to pick up the new manifest between requests.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just roll your own helper method?

```
def subdomain_application_stylesheet_link_tag(subdomain)
  if Rails.env.production?
    # This assumes you've precompiled the spreadsheet into the public directory via sprockets
    stylesheet_link_tag File.basename(
      Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/assets/#{subdomain}-application-*.css").first
    )
  else
    # Logic to development stylesheet selection
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full solution to manifest reloading issue. As stated in the original post, the new manifest.json that you dynamically generate will not reload unless you fully reload your server (or kill works, etc). Just to reiterate:

> If you are dynamically creating assets 'live', along with a manifest
>   to prevent caching, Sprockets doesn't reload the manifest between
>   requests.

I needed this manifest reloading capability for development only because I am rolling-my-own asset pipeline with Gulp for a performance boost. Basically, using this solution allows the assets to function exactly how they would in production, while still being able to live-reload them when developing with a new manifest...pretty slick, I hope you find it useful for your production needs.

create the file config/initializers/live-manifest.rb:

```
  require 'sprockets/rails/helper'
  module Sprockets
    module Rails
      module Helper
        def asset_digest_path(path, options = {})
          # create the new manifest, overriding sprockets' old one
          if assets_manifest and manifest = Sprockets::Manifest.new(assets, Dir.glob(File.join(assets_manifest.dir, 'manifest-*.json')).first)
            if digest_path = manifest.assets[path]
              return digest_path
            end
          end

          if environment = assets_environment
            if asset = environment[path]
              return asset.digest_path
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Also, you're more than welcome to customize the new manifest directory if you desire. Mine is in the same place as the previous, with a different name, as you can see from the Dir.glob method call.